# Creating a dynamic header with JavaScript for jQuery Mobile

Tags: javascript, jquery-mobile, dynamic, header

I want to use JavaScript to create a dynamic toolbar for my jQuery mobile site, but I cannot get my header to appear at all.

---

HTML:

```
<section id="home" class="header_default" data-role="page" data-title="Home">
```

---

JS:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$(document).on("pageshow", "[data-role='page']", function() {
if ($($(this)).hasClass("header_default")) {
   $('<header data-role="header"><a href="index.html" class="ui-btn ui-btn-inline 
   ui-corner-all ui-icon-home ui-nodisc-icon ui-btn-icon-notext ui-btn-b"></a><h1 
   class="logo">Junkless <span id="f">F</span>oods <p id="slogan">unrefined. yet refined.
   </p></h1><a href="#gallery" class="ui-btn ui-corner-all ui-icon-instagram 
   ui-nodisc-icon ui-btn-icon-notext ui-btn-b"></a></header>')
.prependTo( $(this) );

 $.mobile.resetActivePageHeight();

    } //if
  }); //show_page
}); //document.ready
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do `... .prependTo($('body'));` The document element isn't actually a DOM element that is visible on the page.

Also you can simplify your overall code to:

```
$(document).on("pageshow", ".header_default[data-role='page']", function(){
   $('<header data-role="header"><a href="index.html" class="ui-btn ui-btn-inline 
   ui-corner-all ui-icon-home ui-nodisc-icon ui-btn-icon-notext ui-btn-b"></a><h1 
   class="logo">Junkless <span id="f">F</span>oods <p id="slogan">unrefined. yet refined.
   </p></h1><a href="#gallery" class="ui-btn ui-corner-all ui-icon-instagram 
   ui-nodisc-icon ui-btn-icon-notext ui-btn-b"></a></header>').prependTo($('body'));
   $.mobile.resetActivePageHeight();
});
```